# Groovy/Grails unable to resolve class only @ run

Tags: grails

Have a groovy controller leveraging Java SSH package (JSch) with NO ISSUES in IDE (jar was added to library, import works, all calls against class pass) however I get failure only on run-app:

```
unable to resolve class JSch @ ... : JSch jsch = new JSch()
```

I use the same code in Java without any issues for an SFTP application and this won't even instantiate the initial object so less concerned about the rest of the code.  I've tried mucking with dependency mgmt and refreshing with no success.

I guess the question at hand is why does any class fail to resolve only at run when there are no obvious issues with implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah... Grails doesn't give a damn about which jars you add with your IDE. Grails uses Maven to resolve dependencies.

### Next steps

The first thing is to remove the JSch jar. Then, add the following Maven artifact to your project: **com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.53**

Of course, adjust the version number as needed. How this is added to Grails depends on the version of Grails you're using.

#### Grails 3

Add the following to the `dependencies` closure in **build.gradle**:

```
compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.53'
```

#### Grails 2.4

For Grails 2.4 (and maybe earlier versions, I simply don't know) add the following within the `plugins` closure in **grails-app/config/BuildConfig.groovy**

```
compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.53'
```

Comment: bastards!  yeah, i moved over to 3.x after years on 2.x